# is possible on after logon trigger send RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR and keep connected?

Tags: database, oracle

**I need to send a message to users using the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20101, 'Some feature dabase message');
When I use the trigger after logon users are disconnected.**

---

```
create or replace TRIGGER "SYSTEM".LOGON_MENSAGEM_TRIGGER AFTER
LOGON ON DATABASE DECLARE mensagem varchar2(4000) ; 
        INSERIR VARCHAR2(4000); 
        msg_erro exception; 
        PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(msg_erro, -20101);         
BEGIN 

  IF USER in ( 'LTAFARELLO', 'ALEXANDRE','AUSUARIO', 'SIG_EMPLASA\ABARBOZA') THEN   
    FOR consulta IN (select id, owner, TABLE_NAME, DESCRIPTION, CREATED from DICIONARIO_SIGEMPLASA.DICIONARIO_SIGEMPLASA where ID not in (select distinct dicionario_id from DICIONARIO_SIGEMPLASA.USER_DISPLAY where USER_NAME=user )) LOOP 
      mensagem :=mensagem || 'Feição:' || consulta.owner || '.'  || consulta.table_name || ' - Data de Criação:' ||  consulta.created || ' - Descrição: ' || consulta.DESCRIPTION || chr(10) || chr(13) ; 
      INSERT INTO DICIONARIO_SIGEMPLASA.USER_DISPLAY(USER_NAME,DICIONARIO_ID)VALUES( user,consulta.id );       
      INSERIR :=INSERIR || 'INSERT INTO DICIONARIO_SIGEMPLASA.USER_DISPLAY(USER_NAME,DICIONARIO_ID)VALUES('''|| user || ''',' ||consulta.id || ');'; 
     END LOOP; 
     commit; 
       --system.SHOW_USER_MSG(user,mensagem); 
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,mensagem); 

  END IF; 
  end;
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail the flow of events, what you expect and what actually happens.

Comment: No, that is the purpose of an `after logon trigger`. The trigger is actually part of logon procedure, so when you raise an exception then the logon was not successful by definition. Just a note, if you are a DBA (more precisely have `ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER` privilege) then any exception in after logon trigger is ignored, i.e. you can logon anyway.

Comment: I can't get it to work, but there might be a way to do this using specific exceptions that Oracle normally ignores.  For example, many tools know to ignore `ORA-28002: the password will expire within X days`.  There might be some way to hijack that exception and use it to display a message.  But when I try the obvious way it still breaks the connection.

Comment: When we connect with any contact that is in the list, my message apppers, but the user is discinected.
Like this :
conn auser/123@mydb
Error:-20101 Some menssage that was programed
disconected